# Bit model vs RAM model confusion

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

I've been struggling with this analysis of algorithms notion for a few hours now in an introductory course. Let us define a function $N(n)$ for positive integer $n$ as the number of times performing $n=log_7(n)$ yields $\leq 1$. So $N(1)=0, N(7)=1, N(7^7)=2$, et cetera.

I'm asked to find a good algorithm for computing $N(n)$ in both the logarithmic and uniform cost criteria. My current algorithm proposal is as follows:

1. If $n\leq1$, return 0
2. Set $a=7$, $n=1$
3. If $a\geq n$, return $n$ else $n++$ and repeat steps 2-3 until completion

I believe this yields a $O(\log_7{n})$ time complexity (it's below it), but am unsure of what the logarithmic and uniform cost criteria entails in this problem.

Comment: This is called the *iterated logarithm*.  It is worth mentioning it.

Comment: Hint: the cost is $L(n)+L(\log(n))+L(\log(\log(n)))+...$ where $L$ denotes the cost of computing the logarithm. Most probably you can drop all terms but the first.